# Possible to split/cascade getopt_long?

Tags: c, linux, command-line-arguments, getopt

I have a small C (not C++) app that parses command line arguments using `getopt_long`.  I'm wanting to write another app that shares a number of elements (including some common command line parameters) but will have some unique stuff too.  As part of this I would like to split the command-line parsing into common (in a static library) and app-specific.

Is it possible to somehow cascade calls to `getopt_long` with different option sets, such that if the "outer" call (app-specific options) doesn't recognise an option it can try calling the common options parser, without printing any errors to the user unless both don't recognise the option?  This would have to be done on an option-by-option basis as the user would be able to pass the options in any order.

I like the simplicity of getopt's statically-defined constant option lookup tables.  I know I could probably generate a single merged table dynamically and just call getopt the once but that seems more painful and I'd prefer not to have to do that.

My reading of the docs does not look promising thus far.

Comment: do you just want to have two files that use the same options?  Or are you talking about having two different files use different options that are defined by the same code (macros anyone)?

Comment: The library will define options that are common to both/all applications (things like `--verbose` and `--help`); the apps will separately define options that are unique to themselves (eg. `--do-that-thing-with-the-stuff`).  So each app will support both its own options and the common options.  I don't want to duplicate the common options in both apps' code, the whole point of making a library is to remove duplication.  I suppose defined macros could work, and I like that marginally more than dynamic table building, but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: That's just bad design.

Comment: That depends on what you consider _good_ design.  Why write two `.c` files with almost the exact same code when you can just write one and use macros to determine which features to include in which binary?

Comment: Why do either of those things when you can write one .c file that goes into a static library that is compiled into both apps?  (And writing structures in a header file that have different content depending on what .c file is compiled will [a] violate OCP, which can cause compile time and multi-developer conflict problems, and [b] get you in serious aliasing trouble if you ever try to build those things into the same app.)

Answer (score 0):

I would then consider using the [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) API from GNU libc.

Argp parsers can be combined, see [the example 4](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp-Example-4.html#Argp-Example-4). So you would put the common part in one parser (in your shared library), and the application specific parsers in another one.

Alternatively, consider also [*Glib*](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) (from GTK, but usable independently) and its [command line option parsing](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html) (since `GOptionContext`-s can contain several `GOptionGroup`-s with [g_option_context_add_group](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html#g-option-context-add-group) ...)

Comment: Sorry, I missed this answer until now.  I've been using #defines with getopt thus far (common header provides `COMMON_LONG_OPTS` and `COMMON_SHORT_OPTS` that the apps have to stick in the right place), but argp looks like an interesting alternative.  I'll have a look at that further.